# Output is not correct, missing the data after comma

Tags: perl

Below is the code which I have written to compare two files. Basically the program is trying to fetch those records which were present in yesterday's report but not present in today's report file.

**Example**

**File1.txt**

```
1111,1
2222,2
3333,3
4444,4
```

**File2.txt**

```
1111,1
5555,5
6666,6
3333,3
7777,7
```

**Run**

```
perl program.plx File1.txt File2.txt
```

**Output should be**

```
2222,2
4444,4
```

**But I'm getting**

```
2222
4444
```

i.e. I'm missing the data after comma. I think there is some problem in regex part. Kindly let me know where I'm doing wrong. Thanks :)

```
    code deleted due to privacy reasons.
```

Comment: `open my $file_handle, "<", $file_name || die "Error - $OS_ERROR"` means `open my $file_handle, "<", ($file_name || die "Error - $OS_ERROR")`. It'll never die unless the file name is `0` or an empty string, and it will always die then (even if there is a file named `0`).

Comment: You really should have a `return;` at the end of your iterator. Returning the return value of a `while` is ...odd.

Comment: @Chankey Pathak : Is this requirement a part of a bigger requirement? I am asking this because if this is the actual requirement, it could have been obtained with basic unix commands instead of perl. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I would love to see the solution using unix commands too. :)

Comment: @ChankeyPathak: added the solution..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  reason is here:

```
$_[0] =~ /^(.+?)\,\w/ )[0]
```

Your regex only returns the part before the comma. Extending the capture does not solve the problem, though:

```
$_[0] =~ /^(.+?\,\w)/ )[0]
```

The new regex will match the whole string, but the numberic comparison will complain:

```
Argument "1111,1" isn't numeric in numeric eq (==) at
```

Changing `==` to `eq` for string comparison quells the warning, but it is not clear whether you want to compare the whole string.

Comment: Right, it is giving warning but the result is fine.

Comment: What do you think? Should I neglect the warning and use this code or re-code it?

Comment: PS: I want to compare the whole string.

Comment: @ChankeyPathak: Then change `==` to `eq`.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, but your extractor is returning just the part before the comma:

```
my $extractor = sub { ( $_[0] =~ /^(.+?)\,\w/ )[0] };
```

Comment: @ChankeyPathak: depends what do you wanna to achieve? It is not obvious to me, what is the goal of your extractor?

Comment: @ChankeyPathak: his interpretation tells me, that this is not extractor but more like validator.

Answer (score 1):

Using the comm command:

```
$ comm -23 <(sort -n file1) <(sort -n file2)
2222,2
4444,4
```